# Define year for two digits year date format

Tags: r

Suppose I'm converting the below date from character to simple date format in R.

```
character_date <- "19-Jan-44"
date <- as.Date(strptime(x = as.character(character_date), format= "%d-%b-%y"))
> date
[1] "2044-01-19"
```

R assumes it's 2044 instead of 1944 (which is the desired), how do I tell R which year it actually was?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to provide the context as to whether it can be 1944 or 2044

Comment: Then how do you show a date with the year 2044 or 1844? or it has to be assumed that every date is going to belong to 19th century?

Comment: If you always assumr the 20th century, I guess you could just embed it into your string, something like `as.Date(gsub("(.*)-(.*)", "\\1-19\\2", character_date), format= "%d-%b-%Y")` and please please don't use  `strptime` when converting to `Date` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function to do this

```
library(lubridate)
f1 <- function(x, year=1970){
   x <- dmy(x)
   m <- year(x) %% 100
   year(x) <- ifelse(m > year %% 100, 2000+m, 1900+m)
  x
}

f1(character_date)
#[1] "1944-01-19"
```

---

If this always have `19` as prefix for year

```
dmy(sub("-(\\d+)", "-19\\1", character_date))
#[1] "1944-01-19"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append a `"-19"` to the string and do `format = "%d-%b-y-%C"`.